# Spread columns by count in R dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, spread

I have a factor column. I would like to spread into one column for each factor and then fill the gaps by the count of that factor appears for each id. Suppose we have:

```
car <- c("a","b","b","b","c","c","a","b","b","b","c","c")
type <- c("good", "regular", "bad","good", "regular", "bad","good", "regular", "bad","good", "regular", "bad")
car_type <- data.frame(car,type)
```

and get:

```
   car    type
1    a    good
2    b regular
3    b     bad
4    b    good
5    c regular
6    c     bad
7    a    good
8    b regular
9    b     bad
10   b    good
11   c regular
12   c     bad
```

I want this:

```
> results
  car good regular bad
1   a    2       0   0
2   b    2       2   2
3   c    0       2   2
```

I try this using dplyr, but I'm not really use to it, so It doesn't work.

```
car_type %>%
  select(car, type) %>%
  group_by(car) %>%
  mutate(seq = unique(type)) %>%
  spread(seq, type)
```

I would thanks any help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Update for `tidyr::pivot_wider`:

```
library(tidyverse)

car_type %>% 
  count(car, type) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from=type, values_from=n, values_fill=0)
```

### Original Answer

#### With `reshape2`:

```
library(reshape2)

dcast(car_type, car ~ type)
```

If you were going to use `dplyr`, the code would be:

**`dplyr` and `reshape2`**

```
car_type %>% count(car, type) %>%
  dcast(car ~ type, fill=0)
```

**`dplyr` and `tidyr`**

```
car_type %>% count(car, type) %>%
  spread(type, n, fill=0)
```

In each case, `count(car, type)` is equivalent to

```
group_by(car, type) %>% tally
```

or

```
group_by(car, type) %>% summarise(n=n())
```

#### With `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

dcast(setDT(car_type), car ~ type, fill=0)
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this in base R:

```
xtabs(~car+type, car_type)

#   type
#car bad good regular
#  a   0    2       0
#  b   2    2       2
#  c   2    0       2
```

OR

```
table(car_type)
```

Comment: Thanks! Sometimes is more easy than one think.

Comment: Be careful with the table option - on large data sets it will be super slow!